# Inserting a one column wide image or table in twocolumn apa6 document

Tags: multicolumn, apa6, wide-image

I would like to insert an image (or a table) as illustrated below in the minimal example, without it overlapping the right side column. I have tried various suggestions using the multicols package, but it doesn't work for me.

I would like the figure to be centered, and I want to be able to move it between top, here and bottom without it breaking the document, and I want the right side column to simply move down below the image and continue beside the left column.

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}\renewcommand{\danishhyphenmins}{22}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Long Title}
\shorttitle{ShortTitle}

\twoauthors{1}{2}
\twoaffiliations{1}{2}

\abstract{}

\rightheader{Header}
\leftheader{Header}

\begin{document}

\maketitle  
\section{title}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=14cm,height=5cm]{example-image.png}
\caption{A wide figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with `figure*` instead of `figure`?

Comment: (i) `figure*` and `table* are appeared on the top of the next page where is inserted, (ii) on the same page, if there is enough space can appear if you use the package `stfloats`. in midle of the page you can them placed only  with the help of the package `qute`, however than the text flow on page is interrupted. *off-topic*:  (i) for `\lipsum` you not need the package `blindtext`.

Comment: I am absolutely sure I did. But I did it again now and that worked. Must have done something else wrong when I tried it the first time! Thanks, that was easy!